# Contrapositive Inquiry

Tags: logic

Suppose you want to show that $A \implies B$.

This is equivalent to showing $\neg B \implies \neg A$.

But now suppose you show that assuming $\neg B$ it is POSSIBLE that $\neg A$, but not necessarily the case that $\neg A$.

Have you succeeded in showing that $A \implies B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prove that, assuming $\neg B$, it is DEFINITE that $\neg A$.

If the case is not certain, then there are some cases that $A$ is true and $B$ is false together, which means it is not the case that $A\implies B$.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. Assuming that you are not dead, it is possible that you are not right now sitting still. It doesn't follow from that that if you are right now sitting still then you are dead.